# Overwriting parent's theme files in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

It seems like my Wordpress child theme in some cases refuses to use child files and still uses parent's files.

For example I want to override the themex.lesson that is located in the 
**child_theme/framework/classes/themex.lesson.php** folder

Parent's file is in the:

**parent/framework/classes/themex.lesson.php** folder

Changes that I make to the child_theme themex.lesson php are not reflected in live site. Other changes made to the child theme work perfectly fine. 
What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Something similar happens to me. The other files that you edit and overwrite perfectly are in the root folder or are inside of folders or nested folders?

Comment: Files that work fine are in the root folder.

Comment: It's the same problem that I've. I keep looking, if I find a solution will tell you.

Comment: Thanks! 
I believe I found out why I have problems with overwriting the theme.
My theme is set up to read always files from Framework folder of the paren't theme...

Comment: And where you change that your theme don't read the parent's files always?

Comment: In my case it's specified in parent's functions.php. I tried to change but it broke my theme...

Comment: I believe you can force it by referencing the files using get_stylesheet_directory(). Look at my answer below. Hope it helps.
Wordpress is fun but the learning curve is quite a challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Referencing / Including Files in Your Child Theme**

> When you need to include files that reside within your child theme's
>   directory structure, you will use get_stylesheet_directory(). Because
>   the parent template's style.css is replaced by your child theme's
>   style.css, and your style.css resides in the root of your child
>   theme's subdirectory, get_stylesheet_directory() points to your child
>   theme's directory (not the parent theme's directory).
>
> Here's an example, using require_once, that shows how you can use
>   get_stylesheet_directory when referencing a file stored within your
>   child theme's directory structure.\

```
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/my_included_file.php' );
```

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes